# If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices invertible matrices, can the equation $A+B = AB$ be true?

Tags: linear-algebra

We just need to find one example to back this up right?

as answered by @peek-a-boo ,
taking A= B = 2I

$2I + 2I = (2I )(2I)$

$4I = 4I$(TRUE)
Hence, it can be true.

Comment: Yes it can be true. For example if $A=B=2I$. Though as stated, this is pretty trivial, is this really what you intended to ask?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are invertible does not mean they are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us rearrange the equation as $(A-I)(B-I)=I$.  Then as long as $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$, then we can find a $B$ that solves the equation.

If you further want $AB=BA=I$, then $A+A^{-1}=I$, so $A^2-A+I=0$, and so if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2-\lambda +1=0$.  Further, $A$ satisfies an equation with no repeated roots, so $A$ must be diagonalizable.  Therefore, the equation is solvable if and only if $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries equal to $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$

Comment: @user It's impossible to tell if he asked what he meant or not, so I answered with two different interpretations.